# CodeRush Keyboard Navigation

Tags: coderush

Trying to use CodeRush, but can't find how I can choose context menu item using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <Symbol>.
Is there a way to choose popup menu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> item not only by up and down arrows?

*For example:* Visual Studio context menu has underscored symbols almost for each item it has,
and I can open VS context menu by keyboard (special key is next to the right <kbd>Alt</kbd>), then I
can press <kbd>R</kbd> and Refactor menu will be opened, or press <kbd>O</kbd> and Organize usings menu will be opened, but there is no any underscored symbols in CodeRush popup menu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has **6 refactorings**.

In my current version of CodeRush there are:

- **106** CodeProviders (blue items)
- **209** Refactorings (red items)

[ **Note:** *CodeRush will show you only those that apply given your current context, which is why you typically see no more that 8 items.*]

It would therefore not be practical to assign shortcuts to all 315 of these items for use within the popup menu.

However...

The order of the items in this menu changes over time with frequent use. CodeRush is performing statistical analysis of the contexts in which you choose to use each of these. Over time you should find that the item you wish to use is rarely more than 2 items from the top of the list, and is often the first one.

Also you can create your own shortcuts via the options screen.

- DevExpress[\CodeRush]\Options (**Ctrl+Shift+Alt+O**)
- IDE\Shortcuts

[More details here](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/rorybecker/archive/2010/10/05/binding-keys-in-coderush.aspx)

You can attach a shortcut directly to a specific refactoring by specifying 'Refactor' in the shortcut's command box and by providing the name of the refactoring in the parameters box.

**Note:** The above also works for Code Providers (the blue items).

Feel free to ask for clarification of any of these points, or email me if you prefer: roryb@devexpress.com